# Store the if else output in a variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have want to write and store a simple if else output in a value.
I have filenames like this.

US_Sales_2019090200022300023223155

UK_Sales_2019090200022300023223155

Sales_2019090210022300023223155

Sales_2019090210022300023223155

If Country is US or UK , I want to store the output value in Country as US or UK (Country1==file[:2]).
If not I want to store the output value in Country as like 201909021 (Country2==file[5:13])

Please help me.

```
Country==[]
Country1==file[:2]
Country2==file[5:13]

if Country1=='US'|Country1=='UK':
     Country1==Country
else:
     Country2==Country
```

Comment: The assignment operator is `=`, not `==` (which is correct to compare inside the if, but not to assign values to variables).  You also reversed the assignments inside the if statement, should be `Country=Country1` and `Country=Country2`.

Comment: Hi, Could you please write the code. I am newbie. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It is way easier to just scan the entire filename for the country-code instead of specifying where exactly the countrycode could be. 
Like this:

```
file = "UK_Sales_2019090200022300023223155"

if "US" in file:
    Country = "US"
if "UK" in file:
    Country = "UK"
# Add more country-codes, if needed    
else:
    Country = None

print(Country)

>>> UK
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to split file name into pieces:

```
def get_val(fileX):
    if 'UK' in fileX or 'US' in fileX:
         return fileX.split('_')[0]
    else:
        vals = fileX.split('_')[1]
        return vals[:9] # next 9digits

# test
file1 = "UK_Sales_2019090200022300023223155"
file2 = "Sales_2019090210022300023223155"
print(get_val(file1))
print(get_val(file2))
```

Not depending upon your variable name, you can assign it to country or digit code/date may be.